# langid - classify error language identification

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, anaconda, windows64

I am trying to classify several languages from a combination of tweets texts. I am getting `classify` import error.

```
import langid

df1 = pd.read_csv(old_dir+"\\"+"merged_all_csv.csv", sep=',',encoding = "ISO-8859-1",error_bad_lines = False)
        tweetText = df1.TweetText
        for t in tweetText:
            x = langid.classify(str(t))
            if lang_dict[x[0]] not in lang:
                lang[lang_dict[x[0]]] = 1
            else:
                lang[lang_dict[x[0]]] = lang[lang_dict[x[0]]] + 1

        for k, v in lang.items():
            df.set_value(q, 'Language', k)
            df.set_value(q, 'Count', v)
            q = q + 1

        df.to_csv(new_dir+'\\Language_count.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Error:

```
from langid import classify, rank, set_languages

ImportError: cannot import name 'classify'
```

I have updated the packages and still the error is persistent. How to solve this error ?

Comment: Can you verify that you actually installed the package via `pip install langid`?

Comment: Yes I'd..  I did cross check for about 5-6 times..  Removed n reinstalled again

Comment: Can you add the output of pip freeze?

Comment: @JanTrienes `pip freeze` gave me list of packages and the langid is shown as `langid==1.1.6`